# Grammar resources for DELF A1 test

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Are there resources for the required "Grammar" for DELF A1 test?

Answer (score 2):

These two resources may help you:

http://www.leplaisirdapprendre.com/a1-grammaire/

http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/grammaire-francaise/exercice-elementaire

TV5 has a section on **TCF** (not DELF) where you can choose your level (A1, A2, B1, B2) and do some exercises. As these levels are defined by the "French Academy", I suppose the grammar content of each level is the same for both TCF and DELF - so if you want to have a go at the TV5 website, follow this link:

http://apprendre.tv5monde.com/fr/niveaux/a1-debutant

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de programme de grammaire du DELF. C'est un examen calibré sur les descriptifs du CECRL  (Cadre européen commun de référence pour les langues) et le niveau des candidats est apprécié à travers un certain nombre de tâches qu'ils ont à faire dans la langue de l'examen, en français pour le DELF. A1 est le niveau élémentaire.

Sur le site du CIEP (qui est l'organisme qui organise cet examen) on peut trouver :

- [La présentation des épreuves](http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/presentation-des-epreuves#A1)
- [Des exemples de sujets](http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/exemples-des-sujets)

**Quelques sites qui proposent des exercices d'entraînement :**

- Spécifique pour le DELF A1
  [Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/preparation-delf/index.html)
- Non spécifiques
  [Ciel Bretagne](http://www.ciel.fr/apprendre-francais/preparation-examen/comprehension-test.htm) - le niveau de l’exercice est indiqué (A1- A2- etc...)

  Le [CAVILAM](http://www.leplaisirdapprendre.com/a1-grammaire/), annuaire d'exercices de grammaire en ligne pour le niveau A1.

  [Français Facile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-80157.php) exercices de grammaire

  [ABCfrançais](http://www.abcfrancais.com/cours/a1.ph) : exercices de grammaire niveau A1

---

If by required grammar you mean a curriculum, there isn't any. The DELF exam is based on the language competencies described in the CEFR (Common European Framework of Reference for Languages). What is evaluated is the aptitude of the candidates in performing certains tasks in the language, French for DELF.
A1 is elementary level.

On the CIEP website, the agency that organizes the exam (worldwide) you can find :

- [The description of the various tests](http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/presentation-des-epreuves#A1)
- [Example examination tests](http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/exemples-des-sujets)

**A few sites where you will find exercies to train at A1 level:**

- Specific for DELF
  [Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/preparation-delf/index.html),
- Non specific for DELF A1 level exercices

  [Ciel Bretagne](http://www.ciel.fr/apprendre-francais/preparation-examen/comprehension-test.htm) - le niveau de l’exercice est indiqué (A1- A2- etc...)

  Le [CAVILAM](http://www.leplaisirdapprendre.com/a1-grammaire/), annuaire d'exercices de grammaire en ligne pour le niveau A1.

  [Français Facile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-80157.php): grammar

  [ABCfrançais](http://www.abcfrancais.com/cours/a1.ph): grammar